# Why do Indian women wear bangles?

Tags: belief, culture, women, india

Why do Indian women, especially married women, wear bangles?

Comment: According to the doctrines of acupressure,the wrist(where bangles are worn) contains various important points including those of testicles etc.but this is only a possible biological explanation & there must be some spiritual reasons as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two reasonable answers for your question

Reason1:
Normally the wrist portion is in constant activation on any human. Also the pulse beat in this portion is mostly checked for all sorts of ailments. The Bangles used by women are normally in the wrist part of ones hand and its constant friction increases the blood circulation level. Further more the electricity passing out through outer skin is again reverted to one’s own body because of the ring shaped bangles, which has no ends to pass the energy outside but to send it back to the body.

Inorder to put this in control, or in a way we can say to avoid such impatience problem from occuring, women were asked to wear bangles and some other ornaments waist belt, anklets, armlets. Even Ear rings also have their own significance. Read here to know: Why we pierce ears and why we wear ear rings.

Reason2:
Gold is dia-magnetic which means it repels magnetic field. As we are on earth (hopefully you too!:) ), we are surrounded by magnetic fields. Our heart work on small electrical impulses for its functions. When these electrical impulses get opposed by earth's magnetic field, power of the heart to pump the blood reduces. In order to prevent this, we wear gold.

Gold is a dia-magnetic substance and repels magnetic fields. As it is worn upto the heart position (in the form of pendants), heart will not get the interruption of earth's magnetic field. Hence it does not need to do the 'hard work' to pump blood, which ultimately increases the life of heart.

Comment: Scientific reasoning is off-topic on this site. But you can explain it by keeping it as a section in your answer. The main answer should be related to according to Hinduism Scriptures with relevant citations. [Related meta post](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/142/users-asking-for-scientific-answers-reasons)

Comment: Sir I just like to mention that Hinduism follows scientific terms in the name of God.For example, taking Lord Siva's viputhi in forehead after bathing is a must habit. The reason behind is viputhi has the power to grab unwanted water in your forehead which helps you to overcome cough.I mentioned the above in that manner.

Answer (score 2):

> The tradition of wearing of bangles in India began in ancient times.
>   Even today, womenfolk love to enhance their feminine grace and beauty
>   with the help of bangles that are available in variety of forms. The
>   word bangle has been derived from the Hindi word bangri or bangali,
>   which in Sanskrit means the ornament which adorns the arm.
>
> **History of Bangles in India**
>
> There is strong evidence which shows that women have been adorning
>   their arms with bangles since ancient times in India. One of the
>   oldest art objects in India, the bronze figurine of a dancing girl
>   excavated at Mohanjodaro epitomizes the antiquity and the universality
>   of wrist ornaments in India. The figurine stands in the nude with one
>   arm at her hip, the other arm completely weighed down with a
>   collection of bangles. Even the Yakshinis are depicted wearing
>   bangles. Banabhatt’s Kadambari has a reference to Goddess
>   Saraswati – Goddess of Learning, shown as wearing kangans.
>   Ancient fragments testify that bangles were made from terracotta,
>   stone, shell, copper, bronze, gold, silver, lac, glass and almost any
>   material that lent itself to craftsmanship. From simple plain circlets
>   of metal, to ones decorated with etched and exquisite designs of bird
>   and animal-head terminals and studded with gems, bangles in various
>   forms existed in ancient in India.
>
> **Significance of Bangles for Married Women**
>
> Wearing of bangles is considered a must for a married woman in India
>   and are considered to be an important part of Indian bride’s
>   jewellery. In certain communities, there is a custom which says that
>   gold bangles should not be worn alone by married women and should be
>   teamed with glass bangles, popularly known as 'kaanch ki choodiya', as
>   it symbolizes well-being of husband and sons. In some communities
>   women are so superstitious, that even when changing bangles, they
>   never allow their arm to be completely bare. A simple string or even
>   the end of her sari is wrapped around the arm, until the new set is
>   worn. In certain communities, widows are not allowed to wear glass
>   bangles.
>
> **Tradition of Bangles in West Bengal**
>
> While most married women in India wear gold bangles, married women in
>   the eastern state of Bengal wear a pair of white color shakha (shell)
>   and paula (red coral) bangles as a symbol of marriage.
>
> **Tradition of Bangles in Punjab**
>
> In the state of Punjab, bride wears a set of ivory bangles called
>   chooda on each hand for 21 days, or for a year after marriage,
>   depending on family tradition.
>
> **Tradition of Bangles in Rajasthan**
>
> Rajasthani woman wears ivory bangles from her wrist to her upper arm
>   as jewellery of gold for the rest of her life or till her husband is
>   alive. This tradition has become obsolete in present times.
>
> **Tradition of Bangles in Contemporary Times**
>
> In present times, women, in spite of their marital status adorn their
>   arms with bangles that are available in various types and styles as
>   they believe that wearing of jewellery after marriage or before
>   marriage has no relation to their husband's age. Hence, these days,
>   bangle or bracelets are worn by fashion conscious girls with as much
>   style as their mothers and grandmothers wore as part of tradition.
>
> Bangles are vital not just during weddings, but also on the occasion
>   of baby shower, which in the Indian context can be referred to as the
>   bangle ceremony. It is believed to be an event held to ward off evil
>   spirits that might be lurking around the mother-to-be or the baby in
>   the womb. The mother-to-be, full of health and radiance, diverts the
>   evil spiritsp' attention to her arms full of bangles (glass, silver,
>   conch, or shell bangles, depending on the region and community),
>   thereby deflecting danger to her or the baby. The only time that a
>   married woman removes her bangles is either at labour while having a
>   baby or when she is widowed. While the former is significant of an
>   easy delivery, the latter has tragic connotations. That is why, when
>   glass bangles break, it is thought to portend ill luck. Hyderabad and
>   Firozabad are the favourite haunts for those looking for an amazing
>   variety of strikingly beautiful bangles. If you happen to visit these
>   places, you just might chance upon Kasars there, who specialize in the
>   art of making bangles.

[Source](http://www.sanskritimagazine.com/culture/why-do-women-wear-bangles/)

Comment: See [this meta answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/597/3500) to know about Valid sources.

Answer (score -1):

Indian women wear bangles as part of the bride's jewelry and also to enhance their beauty. Married women are not allowed to wear gold bangles alone, but add glass bangles to symbolize the well-being of a husband. This tradition began in the ancient times and Indian women are still practicing it today. Indian bangles are available in a wide range of colors and designs. Some communities do not allow widows to wear glass bangles. Women in certain communities have strong beliefs about bangles, and believe that they should always be worn. Married women in West Bengal wear paula, or red coral, and shakha, or shell, bangles to symbolize marriage.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPexrLXpOcA